# Delay page rendering until images are downloaded

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to delay the page rendering until the images are downloaded to prevent the images from loading in as the page is being painted?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `onload` on your image to detect when it is loaded.

```js
var img = new Image();
img.src = "http://www.mind-coder.com/example.jpg";
img.onload = function() { alert("Height: " + this.height); }
```

Full example below, what does it do:

- A `div` called cover, covers your page before all images are downloaded (maybe showing a message like please loading).
- The JS script (vanilla no jQuery is needed here) searchs for all the images in the page and load them using `src` path stored in `data-src` for each image.
- `onload` executes when the image is loaded and `loadCount` variable keep track of how many images are loaded an checks for the total number in the page.
- When the number of images loaded are the same of the images in the page, hides the cover and it shows your page.

```js
(function() {
  var loadCount = 0;
  var imgs = document.querySelectorAll('img');
  imgs.forEach(function(img) {
img.src = img.dataset.src;
img.onload = function() {
  loadCount++;
  if (loadCount === imgs.length) {
    document.getElementById('cover').style.display = 'none';
  }
};
  });
})()
```

```css
#cover {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="cover">cover - loading</div>
<img data-src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d9/Big_Bear_Valley,_California.jpg">
<img data-src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/92/Big_Sur_Coast_California.JPG">
```

Comment: What if one of the images doesn't load at all (bad URL or something)?

Comment: @nnnnnn thanks for commenting good point (+1), this script shows just the basic concept as OP did not specify that scenario. By the way, it is possible to detect if there a problem with an image loading using `img.onerror` and decide there what to do, example: showing an error message, or showing the page even if one page or more did not load successfully (but I as I sad depends of the OP's use case).

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like below. First set the display:none to your body in html so it will not display anything and then in the below condition

```
$(window).on("load", function() {
    //show the body like below
     $("body").fadeIn(500);
});
```

> body {   display: none; }

Comment: This is nice and simple, and I'd vote for it if the OP had put the "jQuery" tag on their question...